# c++: asm clobber list

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

In g++, clobber lists for asm can be specified, for example:

```
asm ("somecode" : : "r1", "r2", "r3");
```

which means that the asm code changes registers r1, r2, r3.

Now, my changed registers depend on a template parameter `n` (the `asm` block is inside of a template function), and registers r1, ..., rn will be changed. How can I express that?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? With an architecture with that many registers, can't you just pick a few to use and always use those particular registerd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many different register constellations are you confronted with? If not too many, you could provide a specific implementation for each. (**Template Specialization**)

Because, I apprehend that there's no possibility to create "templated statements".

Comment: I'm afraid this will be the solution I'll have to resort to, although `n` can take values between 0 and 120 ...

Comment: Would it be possible to replace `"r1"` etc. by variables of `const char*`? If so, this could be the solution.

Comment: That idea came to my mind, too (don't know if it is syntactically correct), but I could even not think of a way to generate this comma-separated set of `const char*` with a templated number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all the register that you could use in the clobber list, so the compiler doesn't use them to store the value of a variable; I know this is a little bit slower, but if you don't need a very very high optimization, it will work.